# inside iframe which embeded in light switch screen, how to call java script function from the parent custom control element?

Tags: javascript, iframe, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

if i have 2 HTML pages and i embed on of them (child page) inside the other(parent page) using iframe i can call function js function in the child from the parent using

```
window.parent.myfunction();
```

*note: don't work on chrome*

i need to apply this in visual studio light switch

i embed HTML page inside custom control element in light switch screen using iframe and i want to call JavaScript function from the custom control render to use it whit a button inside the iframe (onclick) .. i tried    `window.parent.myfunction();` but it didn't work.

the custom control render

```
myapp.LaunchURL.BigCustom_render = function (element, contentItem) {

    element.innerHTML += '<div id ="mycontent" style="width:100%; height: 100%;"> </div>"';
    document.getElementById("mycontent").innerHTML +=
       '<iframe src="page.html" id ="myframe" name = "myframe" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>';

    var iframe = $('iframe').contents();

    iframe.find('#h2id').text("change the text please");

    iframe.find('#A2').attr("value", "ok this works");

    myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Students.load().then(
        function onComplete(result) {
            var studentNames = "";
            result.results.forEach(function (student) {
                //alert(student.Name);
                studentNames += (student.Name + " ");
            });

           // alert(studentNames);

            iframe.find('#A1').attr("type", "text");
            iframe.find('#A1').attr("value", studentNames);
        }
        );


    function AlertOnChange()
    {

        alert("the student name changes");
    }





    //to have the entire webpage
    $("iframe").parent().parent().css("width", "100%");
    $("iframe").parent().parent().css("height", "1200px");

    //to eliminate the header if you want to
    $("span").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css("width", "0px");
    $("span").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css("height", "0px");

};
```

the HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dating Form</title>
</head>
<body>


    <h2 id="h2id"> the students</h2>
    <br />
    <br />
    <form>

        <input type="button" value="Get Students" onclick="window.parent.AlertOnChange();"></input>
        <br />
        <br />

        <input type="hidden" id="A1" name="A1" value="hidden" onchange="window.parent.AlertOnChange()"> Students Names </input>
        <br />
        <br />

        <input type="text" id="A2" name="A2" value="text this text box"> textbox </input>


    </form>


    <script>
        //function childAlertOnChange()
        //{
        //    //window.parent.AlertOnChange();
        //}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**this button doesn't respond and doesn't do eny thing**

[image: the button don't do eny thing]

Answer (score 1):

i defined the function outside the custom control render and it works

this is my code

```
var AppData;


myapp.LaunchURL.BigCustom_render = function (element, contentItem) {

    element.innerHTML += '<div id ="mycontent" style="width:100%; height: 100%;"> </div>"';
    document.getElementById("mycontent").innerHTML +=
       '<iframe src="page.html" id ="myframe" name = "myframe" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>';

    var iframe = $('iframe').contents();

    iframe.find('#h2id').text("change the text please");

    iframe.find('#A2').attr("value", "ok this works");

    //to have the entire webpage
    $("iframe").parent().parent().css("width", "100%");
    $("iframe").parent().parent().css("height", "1200px");

    //to eliminate the header if you want to
    $("span").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css("width", "0px");
    $("span").parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css("height", "0px");

};



function AlertOnChange() {
    alert("the student name changes");

    AppData.Students.load().then(
    function onComplete(result) {
        var studentNames = "";
        result.results.forEach(function (student) {
            //alert(student.Name);
            studentNames += (student.Name + " ");
        });

        // alert(studentNames);
        alert(studentNames);
        $('iframe').contents().find('#A1').attr("type", "text");
        $('iframe').contents().find('#A1').attr("value", studentNames);
    }
    );

}



myapp.LaunchURL.created = function (screen) {
    // Write code here.
    AppData = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData;
};
```